# AngularJS with Angular-ui-router and jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angular-ui, jquery-file-upload, angular-ui-router

I am using [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to control my states in my AngularJS application. In one partial I use [jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). The problem that I have is that when I use the [example given by jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/angularjs.html), is that it defines the controller in the template like this:

```
<!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
<form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ng-app="demo" 
  data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController" data-file-upload="options" 
  data-ng-class="{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}">
... 
</form>
```

The form tag has `data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController"`. In my controller this creates all the file upload methods needed (like `$scope.submit()` and `$scope.queue`)

The problem is that I define my controllers angular-ui-router style, like this in my `app.js`:

```
$stateProvider.state('upload', {
  url: "/upload",
  views: {
    "upload": { 
      templateUrl: "app/partials/upload.html", 
      controller: 'DemoFileUploadController' 
    },
  }
})
```

But this piece of code causes my file upload methods, not to be loaded (or bound) in my controller (there is no `$scope.submit()` and `$scope.queue`).

**Is there a way I can use angular-ui-router and jquery-file-upload together?**

Comment: The directive file-upload is using scope : true, which is creating a new isolated scope. This is why your parent scope is not binding

Comment: I have read about it http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive, but I can't come up with a clean solution how I can still have the directive's isolated scope (which is preferred) and work with another controller's scope.

Answer (score 1):

My fix is to simply omit the controller when defining the state:

```
$stateProvider.state('upload', {
  url: "/upload",
  views: {
    "upload": { 
      templateUrl: "app/partials/upload.html"
    },
  }
})
```

This way I assign the controller in my template (like in the example `data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController"`). I am still looking for a way to assign my controller via the stateProvider.